# I can write a fib in C(i have a sample), but is there a more effective way like in Python, i get error when i try

Tags: c

This gives first 15 of fibonacci sequence in C language, but I have to write each sequence manually, how do I make it increment the 2 variables instead of having endless amounts of variables? It was a lot easier in C++ and Python, not sure why I can't figure it out in C..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i;
int main()
{

int var = 1;
int var1 = 1;

int var2 = var+var1; 
printf("%d\n", var2);

int var3 = var2+var1;
printf("%d\n", var3);


int var4 = var3+var2; 
printf("%d\n", var4);

int var5 = var4+var3; 
printf("%d\n", var5);

int var6 = var5+var4; 
printf("%d\n", var6);


int var7 = var6+var5; 
printf("%d\n", var7);

int var8 = var7+var6; 
printf("%d\n", var8);

int var9 = var8+var7; 
printf("%d\n", var9);


int var10 = var9+var8; 
printf("%d\n", var10);

int var11 = var10+var9;
printf("%d\n", var11);

int var12 = var11+var10; 
printf("%d\n", var12);


int var13 = var12+var11;
printf("%d\n", var13);

int var14 = var13+var12; 
printf("%d\n", var14);

int var15 = var14+var13;
printf("%d\n", var15);


int var16 = var15+var14; 
printf("%d\n", var16);

int var17 = var16+var15;
printf("%d\n", var17);

int var18 = var17+var16; 
printf("%d\n", var18);


int var19 = var18+var17; 
printf("%d\n", var19);


}
```

Output:
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765

Comment: Welcome to SO. What mechanism of C++ did you use that is not available in C? Using a loop and adding up 2 variables isn't really a problem where one would use OOP stuff in C++.

Comment: Your code is obviously the version that works but is tedious. What errors do you get if you try it the C++ or Python way? And how does your attempt look like?

Comment: I get undefined behavior when i try looping or just const error initializer variable not constant

Comment: Please don't describe it but show it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks key details. It's my guess that you are looking for something like Python's `(x,y)=(y,x+y)`.

```
>>> prev=3
>>> next=8
>>> (prev,next)=(next,prev+next)
>>> prev
8
>>> next
11
>>>
```

Well,

```py
(prev,next)=(next,prev+next)
```

is basically equivalent to

```py
tmp1 = next
tmp2 = prev+next
prev = tmp1
next = tmp2
```

We can swap the last two assignments without breaking anything.

```py
tmp1 = next
tmp2 = prev+next
next = tmp2
prev = tmp1
```

This can be simplified.

```py
this = next
next += prev
prev = this
```

And that's exactly what you'd need to use here.

```c
int n = 10;

if ( n > 0 ) {
   int prev = 0;
   printf( "%d\n", prev );

   int next = 1;
   for ( int i=1; i<n; ++i ) {
      int this = next;
      printf( "%d\n", this );
      next += prev;
      prev = this;
   }
}
```

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7b1YM4r5x) on Compiler Explorer

Note that we can fudge the starting values (1,0 instead of 0,1) to simplify the logic.

```c
int n = 10;

int prev = 1;
int next = 0;

for ( int i=1; i<n; ++i ) {
   int this = next;
   printf( "%d\n", this );

   next += prev;
   prev = this;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sEcMc3E1r) on Compiler Explorer

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind here it is, It just took me a while to figure it out, sorry.

#include <stdio.h>

```
int var = 1;

int var1 = 2;

int main()
{
while (var<100)
{
    var+=var1;
    var1+= var;
printf("%d\n", var);
}

}
```

Comment: That does not produce the correct series. It only prints the 5th term, the 7th term, 9th term.

Comment: @Gerhardh, They thought this was the answer. They were just wrong about it being the answer.